How to correctly update Realm object (Kotlin)
I try to update an object with:
    fun checkEmbeddedPicture() {
        realm.writeBlocking {
            findLatest(this@FeedMedia)?.let {
                it.file_url = "new/file/location"
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, file_url)
    }

I presume the object is updated in the DB, but the Log statement shows the version in memory is not updated.  How can I update the in-memory version of the object?
** Solution: enter link description here

It's great you found an answer but answers should be posted as an answer - not included in the question. More importantly, please don't use links to other sites in questions or answers. Links can break and if that happens, it would invalidate the question, and answer in this case.
